# Converting Java+Selenium+TestNG+Ant project to Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I made a 100% working Java+Selenium+TestNG+Ant project but had too many jar files, so I decided to convert my project to maven (I would like to handle dependencies via pom.xml file).
So, I converted my Eclipse project to Maven and configured pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>EccentexQAMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>EccentexQAMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <selenium.version>2.45.0</selenium.version>
    <overwrite.binaries>false</overwrite.binaries>
    <browser>firefox</browser>
    <threads>1</threads>
    <remote>false</remote>
    <seleniumGridURL/>
    <platform/>
    <browserVersion/>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.10</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.uncommons/reportng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
    <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/velocity/velocity-dep 
<dependency>
    <groupId>velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-dep</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency> -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/saxon 
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0.8</version>
</dependency>-->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.detro.ghostdriver/phantomjsdriver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
    <version>1.60</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.james/apache-mime4j 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>  -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/bsh/bsh -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>bsh</groupId>
    <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
    <version>2.0b4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.jsourcerer.webdriver/JSErrorCollector
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.jsourcerer.webdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>JSErrorCollector</artifactId>
    <version>0.6-atlassian-3</version>
</dependency> -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-exec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
           <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

After that - I deleted .jar files and tried to run my java class as a TestNG, but I got an error:

> [[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class
>   com.solution.testSuite.OpenSolution.SuiteOpenSolution_OpenSolution -
>   unable to resolve class reference IOException [TestNG] Running:
>   C:\Users\akise\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--37600492\testng-customsuite.xml
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
>
> ## =============================================== Default suite Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
>
> [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@3159c4b8: 42 ms [TestNG] Time
>   taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@29ca901e: 1 ms
>   [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 1
>   ms [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@49993335: 6
>   ms [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@7d907bac: 160
>   ms [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@65e2dbf3: 2 ms

Could anybody clarify what I did wrong if I wanted to handle my decencies (jar files) via maven. Or this was just bad idea?

I researched some related links but there is no step by step instructions or examples how to convert ant to maven and a also didn't find similar issues.

Thank you for your responses, if I should add some extra information - just let me know

Comment: What's the name and location of your TestClasses? By default surefire only picks up Classes named *Test.java and located in /src/test/java. Also you might want to check out http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: @tom, I wanted to use Maven only to store external jars cause I have totally different folder structure and file naming convention. Each test suite got his own folder like com.testSuites.<testSuite>.<testCase>

Comment: If you have different folder structures, you should tell maven about it (see http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/ for that), however I'm not sure I'm understanding your problem correctly ... do you run your TestNG Tests as part of the maven build or from some IDE?

Comment: @tom, I had a TestNG + ANT project which I could run from eclipse or bat file. But I had a huge library of jars I had to maintain, so, I decided to convert my project to maven cause I'll be able to handle jar files from one place - pom.xml. I configured pom.xml, but can't run my test cases/suite from eclipse cause of error. I do not run Maven build to run my test, but all jars already uploaded via pom.xml cause I'm using eclipse and my project is Maven project.

Comment: Hmm ok, sorry can't really provide advice for this scenario then, but you might wan't to consider going maven all the way, there is an initial cost but once you're up and running you get IDE Integration etc.

Comment: @tom, got it, thanks!